# gunicorn stopped finding wsgi directory

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I configured a django app with nginx gunicorn and supervisor. Everything has been working fine for months until today. I have not touched any of the config files but somehow I now get a `502 bad gateway` response when trying to access any page of my site.

Gunicorn is at fault here, here the log that it is being output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 162, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inventory4'
```

I am super confused because everything ran well before!

here are my django configs for gunicorn:

settings.py:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'inventory4.wsgi.application'
```

and in wsgi.py:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'inventory4.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and this is what I have in my /etc/supervisor/conf.d/gunicorn.conf

```
directory=/home/ubuntu/exostocksaas
command=/home/ubuntu/exo/bin/gunicorn  --config /home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/config.py --log-level debug --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/exostocksaas/app.sock inventory4.wsgi:application

autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/gunicorn/gunicorn.out.log


[group:guni]
programs:gunicorn
```

here is my config.py file in gunicorn package:

```
BASE_DIR = "/home/ubuntu/"
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)
 
 
bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'
backlog = 2048
 
 
import multiprocessing
daemon: True
workers = 20
worker_class = 'gevent'
worker_connections = 1000
timeout = 300
graceful_timeout = 300
keepalive = 300
inactivity_timeout=300
errorlog = '-'
loglevel = 'info'
accesslog = '-'
threads = 2
```

Honestly, I have just been make updates to the django app, so it is bizarre, anyone has a clue or experience of things that could cause this issue?

something that I am now thinking of, could be that I am having load issues with my virtual machine, could that cause gunicorn to crash?
here is what I notice when I run `landscape-sysinfo`

```
System load:  9.56              Processes:           135
  Usage of /:   80.7% of 7.69GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 38%               IP address for eth0: xxx.xx.xx.xx
  Swap usage:   0%
```

could that be the issue?

Comment: What does `ls -l /home/ubuntu/exostocksaas/inventory4/__init__.py` give you?

Comment: -rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Apr 29  2020 /home/ubuntu/exostocksaas/inventory4/__init__.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue in case someone stumble her, DISCLAIMER ^^ I am not capable of explaining why it stopped working and why the solution fixed the issue.
the error shown in gunicorn log appeared to be a kind of default issue and the real issue was silent. I suspect it to be a CPU problem.

I simply went to /venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/config.conf and added

```
threads = 2
```

it was previously set to one and setting it to two made the trick. I am very open to any better fix, or an explaination of why it solved the problem.

Comment: If you set it back to 1 and stops working, then at least you know it's something related. But what you did is reload the server, so that may just have fixed it. Also you're changing a config that is part of the installed packages, so next time you upgrade your venv, your changes are lost.

Comment: I didnt know about this! do you recommend a way to save the changes made?

Comment: Gunicorn has sane defaults for most things and you override just what you need with command-line arguments. So in this case in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/gunicorn.conf`. Changing threads would be `--threads 2`. I would use `command=/home/ubuntu/exo/bin/gunicorn --chdir /home/ubuntu/exostocksaas --threads 2 --log-level debug --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/exostocksaas/app.sock inventory4.wsgi:application`. The config file is the default config module loaded anyway.

Comment: I understand, I get it, I'll make the change in that instead. But now I am kind of nervous, because I needed to use gevent workers and could only configure in /lib/gunicorn, would your recommand putting that file somewhere else to make sure it dont disapear on venv update?

Comment: You mean [this](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-class)?

Comment: yes sir, and i was only able to set those parameters in the package config file to get the gevent workers up and running because you need to import multiprocesses into the config.py, I update the post to show you